# public button is always set to false

Tags: java, button, netbeans, boolean, logic

here's my problem in java, my button is set on public because it is  on different window and now i put a function to this button but when I always open the window that the button is included the button is always set to false even the button is clicked it is not functioning.

BTW 
***veiwTable*** is a new window:(maybe somebody will laugh to my spelling but I intentionally set it to wrong due to my other variables :) )
***convertToTxt*** is a button

I input ***else*** to check if the function is set to false when opening the window

here is my code:

```
if(veiwTable.convertToTxt.isSelected()) {
        try{
            File file = new File("e:\\Data Logs\\ " + sn + "_" + status + ".txt");
            if(!file.exists()){
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write("Board Name:             " + boardName);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("Part Number:            " + pn);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("Serial Number:          " + sn);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("Board Revision:         " + bRev);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("Failing Test Parameter: " + failingTest);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("Failing Checker:        " + checker);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("Verified By:            " + verifiedBy);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("Remakrs:                " + remarks);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("Tester Number:          " + testerNumber);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("Datalog:");
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write(Datalogs );
            bw.close();
            String note = boardName.concat(" with ").concat(sn).concat(" is located on 'ETS88-spare'\'E:'\'Data Logs'"); //" with " + sn " is located on 'EData Logs'"
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, note);

        }catch(Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    } else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "none");
```

Comment: This is extremely unclear. What button? `my button is set on public` what does this even mean? Your code does not demonstrate the problem. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Okay but where's the button??

Comment: convertToTxt is the button, i set this to public so I can call this button on different window, I'm using java netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

update: my program is now running properly after converting to string all the data on the text box and call it afterwards.

```
private void convertToTxtActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    //////not included on the generated datalogs///
    String lastDevice = jLastDevice.getText(); 
    String progname = jProgramName.getText();
    String progRev = jProgramRevision.getText();
    /////////////////////////////////////////////
    String boardname = jBoardname.getText();
    String pn = jPN.getText();
    String sn = jSN.getText();
    String boardrev = jBoardRev.getText();
    String verifStatus = jVerificationStatus.getText();
    String failedTNum = jFailedTNum.getText();
    String checker = jFailingChecker.getText();
    String tester = jTesterNumber.getText();
    String remarks = jRemarks.getText();
    String verifiedBy = jVerifiedBy.getText();
    String dLogs = jDatalog.getText();

     try{
            File file = new File("\\\\192.168.1.100\\e\\Data Logs\\ " + sn + "_" + verifStatus + ".txt");
            if(!file.exists()){
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write("Board Name                : " + boardname);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("Part Number               : " + pn);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("Serial Number             : " + sn);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("Board Revision            : " + boardrev);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("Failing Test Parameter    : " + failedTNum);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("Failing Checker           : " + checker);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("Verified By               : " + verifiedBy);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("Remakrs                   : " + remarks);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("Tester Number             : " + tester);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("Datalog");
            bw.newLine();
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write(dLogs );
            bw.close();
            String note = boardname.concat(" with ").concat(sn).concat(" is located on 'ETS88-spare'\'E:'\'Data Logs'"); //" with " + sn " is located on 'EData Logs'"
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, note);
            //System.out.println(note);
        }catch(IOException | HeadlessException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }


}
```